# Adobe Flash BOT Detection

Tags: flash

I'm writing bot(Windows) for online flash game. Bots isn't allowed in game - they give permanent ban. I was read some about bot detection. IMO is there 3 ways to detect.

1. BOT is in process list
   I'm thinking that flash player can't access to process list.
2. Click tracking
   Clicks are on random position of icon and on random icons.
3. Mouse tracking
   I'm not sure if flash game can do this but believe that not :-)

My question is: 
Is there another way to detect my bot app and how to prevent it from detection?

Answer (score 1):

- For 1 change the exe name to something less suspicious than "Bot for
  game XZY.exe"
- For 2 do not always click the same X,Y coordinate but define a
  rectangle and randomly choose a point inside as target for click.
- For 3 simply move the mouse along the path between the points and you
  will be fine.